# Do I use Twig filters 'include' and 'extends' for localized site correctly?

Tags: templating, filter, filesystem

I use regular file names for template structure from documentation for clearer understanding.

I have the template structure:

- _layouts

  - base.twig
- _includes

  - header.twig
  - body.twig
  - foot.twig
- index.twig
- de

  - _includes

    - header.twig
    - body.twig
    - foot.twig
  - index.twig

So for top level domain, 'index.twig' `extends` 'base.twig' and 'base.twig' `include` 'header.twig','body.twig' and 'foot.twig'.

For sub level domain (example.com/de), It's the same scenario as for top level domain.

All 'index.twig' files in all sub level domains `extends` the same file located at '_layouts/base.twig'.

The `include` filters look like this in my 'base.twig' template.

`{% block header %}{% include '_includes/header' %}{% endblock %}
{% block body %}{% include '_includes/body' %}{% endblock %}
{% block foot %}{% include '_includes/foot' %}{% endblock %}`

**All work great, but did I use it correctly?**

The thing that confuses me, is that I didn't have to copy '_layouts' folder with 'base.twig' file to 'de' folder, and modify paths in 'base.twig' for all `include` filters. Why is it so? Twig renders files of an active locale?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [localization guide](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/localization-guide#step-7-update-your-templates) - When Craft is looking for a template, it *first* sees if a template with that path exists inside a directory named after the current locale, then for the actual path provided.

So in your case, when you're in the `de` locale, it would look for the following templates:

1. `templates/de/_layouts/base.twig`
2. `templates/_layouts/base.twig`

and

1. `templates/de/_includes/header.twig`
2. `templates/_includes/header.twig`

etc, using the first one that exists.

If there's little or no difference between how the site behaves in different locales (other than the [translated strings](http://buildwithcraft.com/help/static-translations),) then it might not be necessary to override whole templates like that, but it's great when you need it.

Comment: I know, we should avoid in comments here of using words like "Thanks", but Thanks for clarification. Thanks to Twig, that Craft is so great to play with. Love it so far :)